# For camel JmsConfiguration Spring cachingconnectionfactory can be used with JndiObjectFactoryBean inside websphere Appserver

Tags: spring

My application is running under Websphere Application server and uses apache camel for message routing. My QueueConnectionFactories and Queues are created as JMS resources in the Appserver with jndi pointing to WebsphereMQ Queue Manager. Can I use SpringCachingConnectionFactory for better performance inside JEE container like WAS with JNDI. Following spring config:

```
<bean id="jmsDestinationResolver" class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver">
</bean>
<bean id="myJndiObjectFacory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
   <property name="jndiName" value="jms/MyQCF"/>
</bean>
<bean id="myJmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="myJndiObjectFacory"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager"/>
    <property name="destinationResolver" ref="jmsDestinationResolver"/>
```

Will above code have same performance as of spring CachingConnectionFactory ?
or
Is it possible to use CachingConnectionFactory with Jndi lookup in websphere JEE container?